# How to set up dart version in GitHub action?

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a sample project using:

```
Flutter 1.14.6 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fabeb2a16f (7 weeks ago) • 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
Engine • revision c4229bfbba
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)
```

I tried to set up CI on my project but it keeps complaining about version:
[image]

Can anybody tell me why it happen ?